# Placing labels as numbers at the top of each bar in this plot in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, labels

I have this bar chart where numbers seem to appear to be not centered at the top of each bar. I tried writing "center" in the \node area, but it did not work. The code is written using pgfplots. The numbers at the top are some labels of each bar. Below is my code:

```
    \pgfplotsset{
    every axis/.append style={font=\large},}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.35]
  \begin{axis}[
  title=Data,
    xbar, xmin=0,
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\large},
    width=10cm, height=15cm,
    xlabel={\large A},
    symbolic y coords={M1,M2,M3,M4,M5,M6,M7,M8,M9,M10,M11,M12,M13,M14,M15},
    ytick=data,
    nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    ]
    \addplot [color=black,fill=black] coordinates {(0.930,M1) (0.868,M2) (0.857,M3) (0.799,M4) (0.741,M5) (0.858,M6) (0.862,M7) (0.862,M8) (0.862,M9) (0.862,M10) (0.864,M11) (0.865,M12) (0.861,M13) (0.866,M14) (0.868,M15)};
    \node[above right] at (axis cs:0.930,M1) {80};
    \node[above right] at (axis cs:0.868,M2) {50};
    \node[above right] at (axis cs:0.857,M3) {30};
    \node[above right] at (axis cs:0.799,M4) {60};
    \node[above right] at (axis cs:0.741,M5) {70};
    \node[above right] at (axis cs:0.858,M6) {50};
    \node[above right] at (axis cs:0.862,M7) {50};
    \node[above right] at (axis cs:0.862,M8) {80};
    \node[above right] at (axis cs:0.862,M9) {80};
    \node[above right] at (axis cs:0.862,M10) {60};
    \node[above right] at (axis cs:0.864,M11) {70};
    \node[above right] at (axis cs:0.865,M12) {70};
    \node[above right] at (axis cs:0.861,M13) {60};
    \node[above right] at (axis cs:0.866,M14) {60};
    \node[above right] at (axis cs:0.868,M15) {60};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: output bar plot with numbers as labels at top of each bar]

Comment: Change `above right` to `right` in the `\node` specifications.

Answer (score 3):

Change `above right` to `right` in the `\node` options specification:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  every axis/.append style={font=\large},}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \begin{axis}[
  title=Data,
    xbar, xmin=0,
    %every node near coord/.append style={font=\large},
    width=10cm, height=15cm,
    xlabel={\large A},
    symbolic y coords={M1,M2,M3,M4,M5,M6,M7,M8,M9,M10,M11,M12,M13,M14,M15},
    ytick=data,
    %nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    ]
    \addplot [color=black,fill=black] coordinates {(0.930,M1) (0.868,M2) (0.857,M3) (0.799,M4) (0.741,M5) (0.858,M6) (0.862,M7) (0.862,M8) (0.862,M9) (0.862,M10) (0.864,M11) (0.865,M12) (0.861,M13) (0.866,M14) (0.868,M15)};
    \node[right] at (axis cs:0.930,M1) {80};
    \node[right] at (axis cs:0.868,M2) {50};
    \node[right] at (axis cs:0.857,M3) {30};
    \node[right] at (axis cs:0.799,M4) {60};
    \node[right] at (axis cs:0.741,M5) {70};
    \node[right] at (axis cs:0.858,M6) {50};
    \node[right] at (axis cs:0.862,M7) {50};
    \node[right] at (axis cs:0.862,M8) {80};
    \node[right] at (axis cs:0.862,M9) {80};
    \node[right] at (axis cs:0.862,M10) {60};
    \node[right] at (axis cs:0.864,M11) {70};
    \node[right] at (axis cs:0.865,M12) {70};
    \node[right] at (axis cs:0.861,M13) {60};
    \node[right] at (axis cs:0.866,M14) {60};
    \node[right] at (axis cs:0.868,M15) {60};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `above right` means that the anchor for placement will be `south west` which explains the vertical shifting; changing to right means to use the `west` anchor, so no vertical shifting is produced (with respect to the center).